# sql server select where case IN

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

Please help with syntax, i need where IN clause only when parameter = 1 otherwise all records

not working

```
SELECT * FROM T 
    WHERE T.C = 'AAA' 
    AND CASE WHEN @Param = 1 THEN T.ID IN ('1','2','3') END - this condition only needed when @param = 1
```

Im try below, but how get all records?

```
   AND T.ID IN CASE WHEN @Param = 1 THEN ('1','2','3') ELSE -all rows- END
```

Comment: I don't know why people immediately jump to trying to use `CASE` in SQL for this. What's wrong with `@Param = 1 AND T.ID in (1,2,3) OR @Param <> 1` (Or, if `@Param` can only take on two values, say 0 or 1, `@Param = 0 OR T.ID in (1,2,3)`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `CASE` for this.

Rewrite your SQL like this:

```
WHERE
    T.C = 'AAA'
AND (
    (@Param = 1 AND T.ID IN ('1', '2', '3'))
    OR
    (@Param <> 1)
    )
```

Remove whitespace as needed when you understand how/why it works.

It can even be shortened down if we change the order of the `OR` part (not necessary really but easier to understand for us humans then):

```
WHERE
    T.C = 'AAA'
AND (
    @Param <> 1
    OR
    T.ID IN ('1', '2', '3')
    )
```

If @Param is *not* different from 1, it has to be 1, so then you don't need to explicitly check this in the other branch.

Thus the best way to do this is this:

```
WHERE
    T.C = 'AAA'
AND (@Param <> 1 OR T.ID IN ('1', '2', '3'))
```